# Is it impossible to iterate table rows in Oracle PL/SQL without using a cursor?

Tags: oracle-10g, plsql

I wanted to figure out if it was possible to avoid using cursor to iterate the table rows in PL/SQL and tried the following script:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
    v1 tbl_plant.plant_id%type := 0; -- number(10,0)
    v2 tbl_plant.name%type := ''; -- varchar2(50)
begin
    while true
    loop
        select plant_id, name
        into v1, v2
        from tbl_plant
        where rownum = 1
            and plant_id > v1
        order by plant_id;

        exit when sql%rownum = 0;

        dbms_output.put_line(v1 || v2);
    end loop;
end;
```

So I figured that compiler optimizes this into an implicit cursor as `while` loop is used, and tried to circumvent:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
    v1 tbl_plant.plant_id%type := 0;
    v2 tbl_plant.name%type := '';
begin
<<divein>>
        select plant_id, name
        into v1, v2
        from tbl_plant
        where rownum = 1
            and plant_id > v1
        order by plant_id;

        if sql%rownum = 0 then
          goto bailout;
        end if;

        dbms_output.put_line(v1 || v2);
        goto divein;
<<bailout>>
    null;
end;
```

But in both cases I got exactly the same error:

```
PLS-00207: identifier 'ROWNUM', applied to implicit cursor SQL, is not a legal cursor attribute
```

But if I commented out either `while` or `goto` and the labels, eliminating either type of loop, the same select worked fine and returned the first id/name in `tbl_plant` by plant ID.

Is it at all possible to iterate w/o using a cursor?

Comment: Why do you ask?  What problem are you trying to solve?  "without using a cursor" is also rather problematic since each and every `SELECT` statement opens a cursor.  Both your examples use exactly the same number of cursors (or would if they worked).  A `SELECT ... INTO` that returns anything other than 1 row will throw an exception `no_data_found` or `too_many_rows` so it would never make sense to check the `rowcount` (which I assume you meant rather than `rownum`) after doing a `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: As far as I remember there is an attribute `sql%ROWCOUNT`, not `sql%rownum`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid cursor attribute name is one of  `%NOTFOUND`, `%FOUND`, `%ROWCOUNT`, `%ISOPEN`. There is no `%rownum` attribute . In your question you use implicit cursors, so it should be
 `sql%rowcount`.